# Good implementation in Mysql or Python for growing limited Set of values

Tags: python, mysql, optimization, data-structures, set

What is good implementation (speed of inserts/memory/speed of reads) either in Mysql or Python for growing limited Set of values. Maybe not really limited but, Saying Insertion of new values among all values is logarithmic?

> In Mysql: A SET datatype can hold any number of strings from a
>   predefined list of strings specified during table creation

Context:

I am analyzing programming languages tendencies and other correlations based on the history of events happening in Github repositories. The set of languages is naturally limited. My script while discovering new ones the growth is slower than linear and my intuition is that it is logarithmic. Anyway, if there are 100 languages, and 1000000 text to analyse, stacked values speed is like:

[image]

Comment: It sounds like you just want any sort of index or key in a database, or just a `set` in Python. If those wouldn't solve your problem, it would help if you could clarify your requirements. Why do you want a MySQL `SET` instead of having multiple rows in a table?

Comment: making a table for saying 100 rows for let's say 10 millions check_if_exists which is read mostly followed with a write rarely seems not to be the best option. not to mention reads later for exploiting results for analysis. at the other side, making a simple Set for not already known values is not an option, this is why I need a solution in between, if only it exists. If not, a simple table would be my a 1st option. the practical reason for these, is that I am trying to cut time whenever I can, as I am analyzing gigs of data. a 2nd solution, is to grab a list of languages from some source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE Languages (
    lang VARCHAR(222) NOT NULL,
    counter INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL.
    PRIMARY KEY(lang)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

After analyzing a text to decide its language ($lang):

```
INSERT INTO Languages (lang, counter)
    VALUES ($lang, 1)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
        counter = counter + 1;
```

This will be plenty fast (though not the fastest).  It has the added feature of counting occurrences each 'language'.

A MySQL `SET` is probably not suitable because

- When you encounter a new value, you need to `ALTER TABLE`, a 'heavy' operation,
- `SET` is limited to 64 values.